# Postfix delivery notification to multiple local mailboxes

Tags: postfix, email-server

My question regards a postfix setup with virtual domains. The server should send mail with a sender address where the address is not hosted on the sending server. If an email could not be delivered (e.g. the recipients address is incorrect) postfix should deliver a status notification based on the senders address back to a local mailbox, from where I can retrieve it with POP3.

Example:

```
Mail from: john.doe@somedomain.com
Recipient: someone@example.com

If the delivery fails send a delivery status notification back to a local account.
```

Is this somehow possible? I've read things about beeing blacklisted when reverse DNS lookup fails if the mails sender and the domain of the mailserver do not match.

Any answers greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix (and most MTAs) by default will issue an error email to the mail originator, no matter if it's in your local domain or elsewhere.

It'll also send an error email to whoever owns `postmaster` (or is redirected to) so if you can also get a copy that way.

If that's not what you intend could you please ellaborate a bit more on your question? From what I've read this answer is the one you're looking for

Comment: Hi! As always the devil is in the detail. The mail originator is unfortunately not hosted on the same machine as postfix is, so it would deliver the notification to a foreign machine. In the example above "somedomain.com" wouldn't be listed in postfix's virtual_mailbox_domains nor in mydestination. The mail instead should go to a localaccount like: $(localpart)@mydomain.com based on the senders localpart.

Comment: Aaah there you go :) Unfortunately this is not possible, you can only defer your email to the originating address and postmaster (although you have some leeway with locally hosted domains, you can even have one postmaster per domain hosted in your box), for all the options you can use for bounces, doublebounces etc you can check http://www.postfix.org/error.8.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I almost thought that this wouldn't be easily possible. Do you think exim would be capable of doing so? Don't want to start a evaluation on another mailing system, if this is not possible "in general".

Comment: I think I would be able to do this in sendmail but... it's a massive engineering task to get this running on any MTA since it goes against protocol :/